# How to create a polymorphic behavior when sub-classes have extra fields, compared with base-class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

Let us assume we have the following hierarchy:

(It's worth mentioning that the example uses Person-Student case just for the sake of simplicity)

```
class Person
{
   public string Name;
   public int Age;

   public abstract void SayHello();
}

class Student : Person
{
   public double Grade;
   public string SchoolName;

   public override void SayHello()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hi! I'm a student.");
   }
}
```

There might be a lot of other classes which sub-class Person.

From the methods point of view, the Liskov principle is 100% satisfied. Wherever in the code I create an instance of Student (or other sub-class of Person), the appropriate SayHello() method will be called.

From the fields point of view, the Liskov principle is not satisfied at all.

The following piece of code is not working and it looks to me as a bad code design.

```
Person onePerson = new Student();

Console.WriteLine(onePerson.Name);       // OK
Console.WriteLine(onePerson.Age);        // OK
Console.WriteLine(onePerson.Grade);      // NOT OK - Person does not have a Grade field
Console.WriteLine(onePerson.SchoolName); // NOT OK - Person does not have a SchoolName
```

My question is: How can I redesign this code to achieve some sort of a polymorphic behavior ? It makes totally sense for the sub-class to contain Grade and SchoolName, but this destroys the Liskov principle. I cannot access the fields from the sub-class as I tried in the above code. The only solution is to downcast, but this is really a bad practice.

I tried to search for different design patterns, but nothing really fits in my case.
I also read about Inheritance vs. Composition, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: You misunderstand the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The design of your classes does not violate it.

Comment: How would it make sense to access those fields? If you only have a `Person`, how does it even make sense to access one of the specific fields of `Student`? Perhaps there should be an `abstract WriteToConsole()` method

Comment: @Charlieface - I may have a factory, which creates whatever type of an instance I need at some point in time, such as: `Student`, `BusinessMan`, `Teacher`, `Driver` etc. All of these are sub-classes of `Person`, each of them having its own extra fields. I see what you mean about why I would like to access those fields and the `WriteToConsole()` method. But what if I want not only to display something to console but to `person.Grade = 5`.

Comment: Again: how does it make sense for code which has no idea what the object is, to be doing such a thing. You need to separate it out and leave such code up to places which actually have access to the full type information, like an `override` function

Comment: You where asking also for other design patterns. According to your last comment a Person is either a Student Or a Teacher Or a Driver. That typically does not fit the real world. A person can be everything at the same time. A person could even be a Student multiple times at different schools. So Student etc. is more of a "role" of Person and not an "identity" of a Person. So as often a Composition (here a 1*N relation) would be more appropriate then inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have misunderstood the Liskov substitution principle. It says that you should be able to use a `Student` wherever a `Person` is expected. What you're doing is trying to make a `Person` behave like a `Student`; not the same thing at all.

What kind of polymorphic behavior would you expect from a field that only exists in subclasses?

Comment: I may have a factory, which creates whatever type of an instance  I need at some point in time, such as: Student, BusinessMan, Teacher, Driver etc. All of these are sub-classes of Person, each of them having its own extra fields. What if I want to explicitly access the fields of a 'Person person = new Student()' ? I have to downcast, which is bad. As you said, I'm trying to make a Person behave like a Student. Is this a bad approach ? Is there any design I should consider ?

Comment: If Liskov would dictate that a Person is a Student and a Student is a Person then they are equal you don't need both then as they are indistinguishable. "What if I want to explicitly access the fields" - then you need to make sure/test before that your Person is also Student and then do something appropriately like casting.

Answer (score 1):

The generally recommended solution is to only use the interface of your type. But this is sometimes not practical. Say you have a business rule that says every student in grade 5 should get an icecream. You could create an `Person.ShouldGetIcecream()`-method, but that would quickly bloat the interface, and mixes concerns that should likely be separate.

A simple solution would be to just check the type:

```
if(onePerson is Student oneStudent){
   Console.WriteLine(onePerson.Grade);  
   Console.WriteLine(onePerson.SchoolName);
}
```

The obvious problem is that the code can become difficult to maintain if there are type checks all over the place. If you add a new type of person you may need to add a bunch of type checks in various places. This is very easy to forget.

A more advanced alternative would be the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). If you use this the compiler can help you find and fix problems, so every visitor needs to handle every type of person. This can help separating the business rules from the person types.

The best solution really depends on your specific application and use case. General inheritance examples like this are often not good examples of real world use cases. Are you making a HR system? Or statistical modelling software? Or software for attorneys? Each may have a very different view of what a "person" is.

But should a student really inherit from Person? What happens if a person is both a student and a teacher? Or graduates, and are no longer a student? You often want to use [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), so consider adding an `Occupation` type. I would also recommend reading [Eric lippers article on Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) for some insights into the issues of modeling complex systems with types.